# segfault on running gsoap application

Tags: c, web-services, gsoap

I'm using gsoap to communicate with the following webservice:
http://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?wsdl

I've run the soapcpp2 to generate the header files, here's my soapClient.c:
http://pastebin.com/Bjev3dP7

getquote:

```
struct _ns1__GetQuote
{
/// Element "StockSymbol" of XSD type xs:string.
    char*                                StockSymbol                    0;      ///< Optional element.
/// Element "LicenseKey" of XSD type xs:string.
    char*                                LicenseKey                     0;      ///< Optional element.
};

struct _ns1__GetQuoteResponse
{
/// Element "GetQuoteResult" of XSD type "http://ws.cdyne.com/":QuoteData.
    struct ns1__QuoteData*               GetQuoteResult                 1;      ///< Required element.
};
```

here's my code so far:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "DelayedStockQuoteSoap.nsmap"
#include "soapClient.c"

struct _ns1__GetQuote *ns1__GetQuote;
struct _ns1__GetQuoteResponse *response;

main() {
  struct soap *soap ;
  ns1__GetQuote->StockSymbol = "goog";
  ns1__GetQuote->LicenseKey = "0";
  if (soap_call___ns1__GetQuote(soap, NULL, NULL, ns1__GetQuote, &response) == SOAP_OK)
    printf("yay\n");
}
```

I get a segfault as soon as I run this code, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are many errors, nothing is allocated.

First you need to allocate the `struct soap` using:

```
struct soap *soap = soap_new();
```

Next input and output arguments of `GetQuote` method need to be allocated, this could be easily done storing in the stack :

```
struct _ns1__GetQuote ns1__GetQuote;
struct _ns1__GetQuoteResponse response;
```

Putting all together could give something like:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "DelayedStockQuoteSoap.nsmap"
#include "soapClient.c"

main() {
  struct soap *soap = soap_new();
  struct _ns1__GetQuote ns1__GetQuote;
  struct _ns1__GetQuoteResponse response;
  ns1__GetQuote.StockSymbol = "goog";
  ns1__GetQuote.LicenseKey = "0";
  if (soap_call___ns1__GetQuote(soap, NULL, NULL, &ns1__GetQuote, &response) == SOAP_OK)
    printf("yay\n");
}
```